# PDO: FetchAll after SQL INSERT and SELECT multiple statement in one execute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

I need to know how to get the result of a select statement that is executed after an insert statement as one execute in PDO.

My PDO connection parameters are as follows:

```
$opt  = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true];
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

I have the following helper function that i use for my PDO statement Execution:

```
function databaseExecute($SQL, $BIND_P, &$BIND_R) {
    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($SQL);

    if ($stmt->execute($BIND_P)) {
        if ($BIND_R !== false) {
            //Type testing is important here
            $tmp = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $stmt->closeCursor();
            if (!$tmp || count($tmp) == 0) {
                return false;
            }

            $BIND_R = $tmp;
        } else {
            $stmt->closeCursor();
        }

        return true;
    }

    $stmt->closeCursor();
    return false;
}
```

My function itself is:

```
/**
 * Adds the current purchase object to the database table
 * @return true if success
 */
public function pushToDB() {
    global $tbl_purchases;

    //We don't push purchaseID since that field is auto handled by the database

    $sql    = "INSERT INTO " . $tbl_purchases . " (ProductID, UID, TID, GenDate, KeyIDs, Total, Assigned) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";
    $result = array();
    if (databaseExecute($sql, array(
        $this->getProductID(),
        $this->getUID(),
        $this->getTID(),
        $this->getGenDate(),
        $this->getKeyIDsJSON(),
        $this->getTotal(),
        $this->getAssigned(),
    ), $r)) {
        var_dump($result);
        $this->_setPurchaseID($result[0]);
        return true;
    }
    trigger_error("Purchase::pushToDB - Could not push purchase to database", E_USER_ERROR);
    return false;
}
```

But this throws a general error 
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error when i attempt to `fetchAll`

In this situation, how do i get the result of the SQL execution?

PS: Using Two executes is not acceptable here.

Comment: 1. PDO can't execute multiple queries. 2. For getting last insert id there's `PDO::lastInsertId()` function.

Comment: According to this it can, https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#multiquery

Comment: It can but you don't need it

Comment: Tell me how do I not need it, if multiple queries are running?

Comment: It's simple. Your knowledge is limited, so you *imagine* you need it. In reality you don't. Other queries out of business here

Comment: So you're saying MariaDB will sit there and wait until PHP gets to the PDO::lastInsertID() function? That's rather silly.. multiple PHP workers can be accessing this table at the same time, as far as I can tell, there is nothing in that function that will prevent me from getting the ID of one of their inserts instead of mine

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#affected says it's not silly: "An answer to a frequently asked question, "whether this function is safe to use in concurrent environment?" is positive: yes, it is safe. Being just an interface to MySQL C API mysql_insert_id() function it's perfectly safe."

Comment: I mean multiple users accessing the site, not multiple MYSQL users, the MYSQL user is the same one. Am i still guaranteed not to run into concurrency issues then?

Comment: According to this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-insert-id.html , it is unique on a per-connection basis, so does that mean that if i switch to a persistent connection it could be an issue?

Comment: Persistent connections has nothing to do here.

Comment: OK, so for persistent connections it can be an issue but its not here because the connection is not persistent? correct?

Comment: OMG. Persistent connections has nothing to do with your fears at all. They are connections all the same, and behave the same way.

Comment: Persistent connection.. as in 1 connection for all PHP scripts. Why is this so difficult to grasp?

Comment: One connection for all php scripts is __not__ a persistent connection. Make sure you understand term `persistent connection`

Comment: A connection that is setup once, used globally and not torn-down. From http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php `Many web applications will benefit from making persistent connections to database servers. Persistent connections are not closed at the end of the script, but are cached and re-used when another script requests a connection using the same credentials. The persistent connection cache allows you to avoid the overhead of establishing a new connection every time a script needs to talk to a database, resulting in a faster web application.`

Comment: You own the connection until you disconnect (or die).  Therefore, the `LAST_INSERT_ID` is available to you, _and only you_, until you reach for it (or abandon it, by issuing another SQL statement).

Answer (score 1):

> Using Two executes is not acceptable here.

This is but a delusion.

Use either second query or - better - a dedicated function PDO::LastInsertId(). But with your rather poorly designed function it could be a problem. So be it 2 queries.

So change your functions to

```
function databaseExecute($SQL, $BIND_P = array();) {
    global $conn;
    if (!$BIND_P)
    {
        return $conn->query($SQL);
    }
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($SQL);
    $stmt->execute($BIND_P);
    return $stmt;
}
```

and

```
public function pushToDB() {
    global $tbl_purchases;

    //We don't push purchaseID since that field is auto handled by the database

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_purchases 
            (ProductID, UID, TID, GenDate, KeyIDs, Total, Assigned) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    databaseExecute($sql, array(
        $this->getProductID(),
        $this->getUID(),
        $this->getTID(),
        $this->getGenDate(),
        $this->getKeyIDsJSON(),
        $this->getTotal(),
        $this->getAssigned(),
    ));
        $id = databaseExecute("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")->fetchColumn();
        $this->_setPurchaseID($db);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your databaseExectute function to take an extra parameter of 'SecondResult' (for example), then change it to something like...

```
function databaseExecute($SQL, $BIND_P, &$BIND_R,$SecondResult) {
    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($SQL);

    if ($stmt->execute($BIND_P)) {
        if ($BIND_R !== false) {
            //Type testing is important here
            if ($SecondResult) $stmt->nextRowSet(); // this will ensure that the fetchAll will return the data from the 2nd query
            $tmp = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $stmt->closeCursor();
            if (!$tmp || count($tmp) == 0) {
                return false;
            }

            $BIND_R = $tmp;
        } else {
            $stmt->closeCursor();
        }

        return true;
    }

    $stmt->closeCursor();
    return false;
}
```

I just typed this in to here directly, I haven't tested it, but it should work.

Also, I'm not saying that the other comments are wrong, and there might be a better way of doing this, but you CAN run two queries within the same 'statement'.